# Converter Python3.7 para exe

Tags: python-3.x

Estou criando um "jogo" sem interface gráfica, para me distrair daquela programação acostumada do dia a dia. Usando Python3.7.0 e SQLite3.

Gostaria de 'proteger' o código fonte do jogo para que não possa ser feito alterações que burlem etapas do game.

O único meio de eu fazer isto creio que é transformando o arquivo Python em um executável, como posso transformar para um .exe ??

Comment: Existe um bug, então para esta versão. Duplicata [desta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/316720/75104)

Comment: Olá @Carlos Pereira, se voce estiver usando uma engine conhecida, como cocos 2d, unity e etc. Voce tera que verificar quais arquivos devem ser colocados no deploy do codigo para funcionar corretamente, algumas engines ja te dam o passo a passo para fazer o deploy correto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode usar módulos como Pyinstaller, py2exe, cxfreeze... Entre outros.

[Como transformar um .py em um .exe?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/164191/como-transformar-um-py-em-um-exe)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10592913/how-do-i-convert-a-python-program-to-a-runnable-exe-windows-program

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14165398/a-good-python-to-exe-compiler

Mesmo assim seu código ainda é vulnerável à disassembling, o que você pode fazer é ofuscar seu código, usando variáveis que dificultam o entendimento, quebrando legibilidade, usando caracteres diferentes e etc sem impactar nos códigos.

Existem ferramentas que fazem isto automaticamente, não sei se é o aplicável ao que você quer, mas é bom eu comentar sobre.